# jrtplib-3.11.1 Why traverse all fd instead of fd with data readable?

Tags: c++, rtp

```cpp
// JRTPLIB 3.11.1, file path : JRTPLIB / src / rtptcptransmitter.cpp, line 292 - 317

// RTPSession::DeleteDestination(RTPTCPAddress(sock_with_no_data_readable))
// manually delete the fd with no data readable from the m_destSockets queue lead to sys cpu reduce to low rate!

// from line 280 - 324, JRTPLIB / src / rtptcptransmitter.cpp

    std::map<SocketType, SocketData>::iterator it = m_destSockets.begin();
    std::map<SocketType, SocketData>::iterator end = m_destSockets.end();

    status = PollSocket(sock, it->second);
```

I hope find better solution that lower the cpu occupancy!

Why traverse all fd instead of fd with data readable ? Using "traverse all fd" strategy will lead to the following problems. When there are a large number of fd with no data readable in the m_destSockets queue, the sys CPU occupancy rate reaches 100 % .